# First application of fertilizer/pesticide (lawn food with crab grass preventer)

Tags: dandelions

I put the crabgrass preventer with lawn food down since it says it’s suppose to be applied first in the early spring. My yard is covered with dandelions but I guess it doesn’t kill them. Do I have to wait until 6-8 weeks before I put my weed and feed down ? Why wouldn’t they put dandelion killer in the first application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most specific pesticides are  ineffective while the target plant is dormant (or still seed).

Crabgrass starts growing very early in the season (the general rule is to treat it before the forsythia bloom).

Dandelions start growing much later in the season.

Any product that is effective against both plants would be useless against dandelions if used in crabgrass season and useless against crabgrass if used in dandelion season.

Answer (score 2):

Crabgrass preventer is a pre-emergent herbicide, which means that it prevents seeds from sprouting; since your dandelion plants have already sprouted, it will do nothing to them. It may, however, prevent seeds from any other annual weed in your lawn from sprouting

Weed-and-Feed is a post-emergent herbicide which will do nothing to prevent crabgrass and any other annual weeds, but is effective on **growing** weeds that are already in your lawn. The six week window you refer to sounds like a guideline designed to help you time when dandelions, chickweed, etc. have begun growing. It may not apply to your area. For example, in my US Zone 5 lawn, my dandelions are growing nicely and have already been treated.